# Material-UI prevent Accordion default collapse on AccordionDetails click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, accordion

I have a React web with two equal menus, so I've made a component with the menu and I render it twice in App component.

For the menu I use [Material UI Accordion](https://material-ui.com/api/accordion/) but when I click on the menu details, the menu colapses by defaul. How can I prevent that?

Here is an example code: [codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-hoover-ome7l)

I don't care about the functionality of the example, I only want to be able to click on menu details without closing it and execute onClick function.

Comment: Set "defaultExpanded" props for default expansion & "expanded" for manually handling it.

Comment: @Madhuri I don't want the menus to be default expanded and I already tried to handeling expansion with ```expanded``` props using a state variable. But It's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also starting with React but I removed the code onClick = {() => handleClick (option)} and the menu is working, I'll try to check something else to help you.

Comment: Thanks, but I need on Click function